# Почему после интерпретации функции в цикле ничего не выводиться (iPython)?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

почему функция вне цикла возвращает свое значения, но как только мы вписываем её в цикл, после интерпретации ничего не происходит?
Например:

```py
def write(a):
    n = a
    return n

for i in range(5):
    write(5)
```

Помогите пожалуйста, буду очень благодарен!

Comment: Измените настройки https://stackoverflow.com/a/36835741/5201699 и будете видеть вывод всех переменных/функций

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша функция никак не выводит своего значения на печать.

Jupyter (так же как и интерактивный режим питона), обычно выводит на печать значение последнего вычисленного выражение, если это значение не None. Но это именно особенность конкретной среды исполнения. Обычно же не следует рассчитывать, что код будет что-то выводить на экран, если в нём нет явной команды сделать это.

Поэтому если вы хотите что-то напечатать, то следует явно делать это командой print.